# Django database update + celery recurrent task

Tags: django, asynchronous, celery

I'm using django + celery and having some problems with concurrency.

I have the following scenery:

One endpoint that updates an object called Route and a celery task that runs each 5 seconds that do some actions based on that Route object data.. The problem is, sometimes the action from my endpoint happens so closely to the celery task execution that the object wasn't updated on the database yet resulting in wrong interpretation.

I'm reading about atomic transactions but don't know for sure how to implement that in my case.

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you try updating the same object at the same time, you are bound to lose data eventually or exceed concurrent DB connections. Why not use polling without a queue with a package like htmx if you need near real-time updates and ensure that the object updates do not conflict?

Comment: I really think I can achieve that with atomic requests on django. I'm trying right now to call my celery tasks like that:

@shared_task
def check_route():
    transaction.on_commit(lambda: check_route_func())

Trying to prevent then to be triggered if there is a transaction happening.